# Multiple pattern replacement in sed

Tags: sed

I have a sed script to add a new line character in front of each keyword.

```
sed 's/select/\n&/ig;s/where/\n&/ig;s/from/\n&/ig;s/and/\n&/ig'
```

is there way to shorten it? I tried the below but it did not work.

```
sed 's/\(select|where|from|and\)/\n&/ig'
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
sed 's/select\|where\|from\|and/\n&/ig' file
```

Using GNU sed:

```
 sed -r 's/select|where|from|and/\n&/ig' file
```

Comment: Both are using GNU sed, posix version doesn not allow the pipe behavior